# C++ и OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Помогите, написал первую программку с OpenGL
Но при посnроении Release:

```
glut32.lib(glut32.dll) : error LNK2026: небезопасный модуль для образа SAFESEH.
glut32.lib(glut32.dll) : error LNK2026: небезопасный модуль для образа SAFESEH.

c:\users\мирослав\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Проект1\Release\Проект1.exe : fatal error LNK1281: Не удается создать образ SAFESEH.
```

При построении Debug такой проблемы нет.

Использую `Visual Studio Ultimate 2012`

Comment: Русская Visual Studio беспощадна!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ есть [тут](http://www.wasm.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=46774), который взят с MSDN [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9a89h429.aspx):

1. Откройте диалоговое окно Страницы свойств проекта. Дополнительные сведения см. в разделе Задание свойств проекта C++;
2. Выберите папку Компоновщик;
3. Выберите страницу свойств Командная строка;
4. Введите параметр /SAFESEH:NO в поле Дополнительные параметры.

Сам сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой и чтобы не оставлять вопрос открытым, решил ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Я подобную ошибку видел, когда линковалась библиотека собранная в другой версии VS. Под рукой сейчас нет студии, чтобы сказать точно, но где-то в настройках у него была галка которая отключает проверку.

Answer (score -1):

Добавите эти строки в самом начале, там где библиотеки подключаете. Должно заработать, Если файлы все на месте. Это только для визуалок. Если их там нет то вам напишет что невозможно открыть файл тот которого нет.

```
    #pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"Glaux.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"GLU32.lib")
```